# I can't print the query results from my database through php, nothing happens

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to echo the query made to my database. So far the code runs but nothing happens. I'm very new at coding so help or an explanation about what I'm doing wrong would be awesome! Thanks a lot!!!

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";

// REPLACE with your Database name
$dbname = "dbsname";
// REPLACE with Database user
$username = "username";
// REPLACE with Database user password
$password = "password";


$ID = 1;

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "Error de conexion.";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE ID = '1' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sensor_data[] = $data;
}

echo $data;

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is data in your database that matches the WHERE?

Comment: Yes!! "ID" is the name of the column which is too the primary key of my table "registro". I've only two entries, the first having an "ID" value of "1", which is the query I'm interested in

Comment: Move the echo in the while loop.

Comment: What is this supposed to be doing: `$sensor_data[] = $data`?

Comment: $data is an array of the last row when you echo it, can’t echo an array directly.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone who replied, @AbraCadaver was right, I can't echo an array so I used print_r() instead and printed the variable $data. Now the php file prints the array with the query results. Thank you all!

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE ID = $ID";

    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $sensor_data[] = $data;
        print_r($data);
    }
```